Trying to figure out why my GoogleSheets Date formula is not working
I have my Order Date in Column A, and Column B which has the number of years to add Column A.
Say the Date in Column A is: 1/1/2024, and the number in Column B is 10.
Ideally, I want the formula to show: =Date((year(A2+B2),month(A2),day(B2+5)), which gives 1/6/2034.
However, the formula is not working. I ensured Column A is formatted to Date in the Format options.
It is just not adding the number of years(10) to the reference year in cell A2.
I ensured my locale and time settings are in the US (Eastern Time).
Any help is appreciated as I have used this formula multiple times in the past without any issues.


Try with:
=date(year(A2)+B2,month(A2),day(A2+5))

